# How to filter a message in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to create a Dashboard in which the message field has the following entry

```
echo <version>
```

The version keeps on changing per execution. I want the Dashboard to display all version and corresponding count. How do I configure the dashboard to visualize the same?

Comment: How is the data indexed in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the timelion to achieve it